# How to convert stdin input to list in R

Tags: r

I have a below stdin input and I am trying to convert this input to a list.

**Input**

```
input <- suppressWarnings(readLines(stdin(), n=31))
8 30
a   s   3
b   s   5
s   a   3
b   a   1
c   a   10
d   a   11
s   b   5
a   b   3
c   b   2
d   b   3
a   c   10
b   c   2
d   c   3
e   c   7
f   c   12
a   d   15
b   d   7
c   d   2
e   d   11
f   d   2
c   e   7
d   e   11
f   e   3
z   e   2
c   f   12
d   f   2
e   f   3
z   f   2
e   z   2
f   z   2
```

Line 1 first value denotes total number of alphabets , Second value denotes total number of rows.
From Line 2 to Line n. First value denotes starting node , second is ending node and third is cost.

I want to group the alphabets and cost as a list in below manner.

**Expected output**

```
> alphabets
$s
[1] "a" "b"

$a
[1] "s" "b" "c" "d"

$b
[1] "s" "a" "c" "d"

$c
[1] "a" "b" "d" "e" "f"

$d
[1] "a" "b" "c" "e" "f"

$e
[1] "c" "d" "f" "z"

$f
[1] "c" "d" "e" "z"

$z
[1] "e" "f"


> cost
$s
[1] 3 5

$a
[1]  3  1 10 11

$b
[1] 5 3 2 3

$c
[1] 10  2  3  7 12

$d
[1] 15  7  2 11  2

$e
[1]  7 11  3  2

$f
[1] 12  2  3  2

$z
[1] 2 2
```

Any suggestions from where to start.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this give you what you want? I convert your input to a data.frame and the split based on your second column. The output of this differs slightly from yours since `split` will sort. If you do not want that, you can order the output based on the input.

```r
df <- read.table(textConnection(input[-1]))

alphabets <- split(df$V1, df$V2)
cost <- split(df$V3, df$V2)

# you can do this to reorder how you had it
order <- unique(df$V2)
alphabets[order]
cost[order]
```

Comment: Thanks.. this is what I wanted. Yor are my saviour of the day !!!

Comment: Hi adam. i tried for this input.. > input
[1] "5 6"    "1 2 30" "1 3 10" "5 2 40" "3 5 20" "2 5 30" "5 4 20" .   alphabets$1 is not getting grouped in alphabets list.

Comment: @ChennaiCheetah that is because there is no `1` in the second column. You would have to have some vector of names you were expecting and then add them in as empty if they are not found.